# Lodash: difference in performance between _.filter and _.each

Tags: javascript, lodash

Given these two snippets, what would be more efficient (considering data sets of around 20,000 points):

`_.each` snippet:

```
var someIds = getIds(); //someIds is an array of ids in data
var resultEach = [];
_.each(data, function(dataItem, index){
   if (someIds.indexOf(dataItem.id) != -1){
       resultEach.push(dataItem);
   }
});
```

`_.filter` snippet:

```
var someIds = getIds(); //someIds is an array of ids in data
var resultEach = _.filter(data, function (dataItem) {
  return someIds.indexOf(dataItem.id) != -1;
});
```

I've ran this test: http://jsperf.com/filter-vs-each-lodash
It seems that filter is a bit faster than the _.each...
Here's another a bit more complex example:
http://jsperf.com/complex-filter-vs-each-lodash

Do you know what is the source of the difference?

Comment: Why don't you try it on jsperf and find out for yourself?

Comment: Look at their source, Luke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both doing essentially the same thing. Both functions will use the same style of `while` loop to iterate over the collection. From a performance perspective, you're comparing apples to apples. From a functionality perspective, `filter()` is more concise and is better suited for the task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash is the great library to perform the task related to utilities like uniq,filter and each.The implementation of the _.each is done much efficient way in lodash over the angular.forEach which much appreciable.
But _.each and _.filter are the method are doing the same job but filter is quite efficient when json structure is simple,small in size and syntactically bit efficient.where _.each is much efficient when JSON is large and complex.

Here is the below link where I have noted the execution time of *.each and*.timer.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8cnfvg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[image]